# CPP: Dynamicly change a typedef in a Class wothout using inheritance?

Tags: c++, eigen, typedef

So I am trying to extend a software. Now the software has a central DataStorage class which uses typedefs and dependent on that some set and get funcitons. Now with my extension the following typedef is not always right:

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<unsigned char, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> eType;
```

Dependent on the argument that is passed before running the software, I would no need to change it to :

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> eType;
```

1. Now I thought about `deriving an alternative class from the class`, but that dataContainer is used at so many places, that it would be difficult to keep track and change where it would be needed.
2. `Dynamically changing the typedef` dependend on the passed argument is not possible right?
3. `Using auto` as a scalar type in Eigen is also not possible?

Is there any easy way to solve this? I am really trying to avoid to derive a new Class from it, since the function of the DataStorage are used everywhere in the code and some classes have that class as a member which also could make errors.

Comment: There's missing still more context. How DataStorage looks like for example. And what parameters you're talking about.

Comment: I would make `DataStorage` a template class, and call the class with the wanted type in the start of your program. However, some refactoring will probably be needed.

Comment: I understood that you want to support two different types simultaneously. If not, and you only need `float`, you're right. If you still want them both, I suggest to read a bit about templates and try using them here.
BTW, since `Eigen::Matrix<...>` is a template itself, you've already worked with a template ;)

Comment: @unddoch improved my basic understanding of typedefs and templates, please excuse my first answers. I think making the datastorage a template class is not a goot idea in my case, other dataclasses use it as a member. I think the best would be to inherit two classed from the base datastorage class and overwrite functions and members. And trying to solve that typedef..

Comment: I agree with @unddoch that templating your DataStorage is likely the best option. Otherwise for your Q2, you could use std::variant or a union to make it dynamic at runtime.